# Setting a default nginx location

Tags: nginx

I'm building a MEAN stack application which is behind nginx

The angular side of my application is all generic and will react differently depending on what URL the user goes to i.e if the user goes to my.app/cars it will go to a different web page than if the user goes to my.app/bicycles

Before the angular side of my application was generic, my nginx development file had all URLs hard coded

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /cars {
        ...
    }

    ....
}
```

However, now that the angular porition is generic, I want my nginx to set all requests to angular by default.

I'be been looking around online, and it seems that having

```
location / {
    ....
}
```

should achieve this, however, when I do this, I get a "this site can't be reached" error.

Any advice on how to achieve what I'm doing wrong to set nginx to angular by default?

I assume people do this if they have a "page not found" error however again I can't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple:

```
location / {
    root /your/app/directory;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

you just need to tell nginx what to do if it cannot find a file.
`try_files` will solve this issue for you.

if you request `example.com/foo/bar/123`

then it will try the following:

1. `$uri` > `/your/app/directory/foo/bar/123`
2. `$uri/` > `/your/app/directory/foo/bar/123/index.html` (this is from the `index` directive)
3. `/index.html` > `/your/app/directory/index.html`

PS:

if you specify `try_files $uri $uri/ /;`

then the last rule will take the index directive into account. similar to the second directive.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for such an in depth answer. Thought it was something simple I was missing in the location (some regexp or something) so good to know it wasn't something like that